MBTiles overview factor '511' is not a power of 2
I am creating an MBTiles archive with the following command
gdal_translate myfile.vrt myfile.mbtiles -of MBTILES -co BLOCKSIZE=256 -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -co ZLEVEL=6

and then want to add overviews with
gdaladdo -r bilinear myfile.mbtiles -minsize 256 --debug on

This works well for some of my datasets. But for one dataset, I get this error
ERROR 5: Overview factor '511' is not a power of 2 
Overview building failed.

I have also tried different resampling methods and values for minsize but this changed nothing. I created another MBTiles archive of the same VRT where I set "ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=UPPER" in gdal_translate. This resulted in an MBTiles archive with zoom level 22 instead of 21. In this case the error message changed to "Overview factor '513' is not a power of 2".
The full debug output is
MBTILES: SELECT value FROM metadata WHERE name = 'minzoom' UNION ALL SELECT value FROM metadata WHERE name = 'maxzoom'
SQLite: 2 features read on layer 'SELECT'.
MBTILES: SELECT value FROM metadata WHERE name = 'bounds'
SQLite: 1 features read on layer 'SELECT'.
MBTILES: SELECT tile_data FROM tiles WHERE tile_column = 1127642 AND tile_row = 1374538 AND zoom_level = 21
MBTILES: SELECT tile_data FROM tiles WHERE zoom_level = 21 LIMIT 1
OGR: OGRGeometryFactory::createFromWkb() - got corrupt data.
89504E470D0A1A0A00
GDAL: On-demand registering /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdalplugins/gdal_PNG.so using GDALRegister_PNG.
GDAL: GDALOpen(/vsimem/0x55ba443b67a0, this=0x55ba4434c2a0) succeeds as PNG.
GDAL: GDALClose(/vsimem/0x55ba443b67a0, this=0x55ba4434c2a0)
SQLite: 1 features read on layer 'SELECT'.
SQLite: 8 features read on layer 'SELECT'.
GDAL: GDALOpen(orthophoto_burned_.mbtiles, this=0x55ba446394b0) succeeds as MBTiles.
ERROR 5: Overview factor '511' is not a power of 2
Overview building failed.
GDAL: GDALClose(orthophoto_burned_.mbtiles, this=0x55ba446394b0)

The output of gdalinfo for the MBTiles archive is
Driver: MBTiles/MBTiles
Files: orthophoto_burned_.mbtiles
Size is 74626, 40699
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2296)"],
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Web mapping and visualisation."],
        AREA["World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N."],
        BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]],
    ID["EPSG",3857]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (1508116.288539087632671,6230423.442114247009158)
Pixel Size = (0.074645535434742,-0.074645535434742)
Metadata:
  ZOOM_LEVEL=21
  name=orthophoto_burned
  type=overlay
  description=orthophoto_burned
  version=1.1
  format=png
  bounds=13.5476391222426873,48.7194152368927007,13.5976797547290325,48.7374170436334566
  minzoom=21
  maxzoom=21
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1508116.289, 6230423.442) ( 13d32'51.50"E, 48d44'14.70"N)
Lower Left  ( 1508116.289, 6227385.443) ( 13d32'51.50"E, 48d43' 9.89"N)
Upper Right ( 1513686.786, 6230423.442) ( 13d35'51.65"E, 48d44'14.70"N)
Lower Right ( 1513686.786, 6227385.443) ( 13d35'51.65"E, 48d43' 9.89"N)
Center      ( 1510901.537, 6228904.443) ( 13d34'21.57"E, 48d43'42.30"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha

I've searched on the Internet already for a while but I did not find any similar report.
Do you have any ideas on this?

What overviews gdaladdo creates if you omit -minsize?

Without the explicit -minsize the same error is thrown as GDAL uses the default -minsize 256. The only way to add the overviews is to explicitly add them with gdaladdo -r bilinear myfile.mbtiles 2 4 8 16. But since my datasets have different sizes I need the number of overviews to be computed dynamically as should be the case with -minsize.

Feels like wrong rounding or something when the automatic zoom levels are calculated. Perhaps happens only with certain base map size because I do not remember other similar reports. The feature of automatic overview levels was added in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/b695992377579ea9e6614e5beefaaf43df7567d7 if you want to have a look at the code. But maybe your issue happens only with MBTiles.
